# discover degree with pydot?

Tags: pydot, pygraphviz

After a little work with pygraphviz I've returned to pydot. One of the useful methods in pygraphviz is iterdegree(). Can something analogous be done with pydot? ie: find the highest degree node so that I can set it as root?

jjc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No answer after a year and a half? I don't think there is a way with Pydot without writing some code.

But you could use NetworkX with the [networkx.from_pydot()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.8/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.from_pydot.html) function to convert to a NetworkX graph object and then call the degree() method.

Comment: I know, right? Thanks for your interest. I wound up using pygraphviz, but since then, I've discovered that NetworkX integrates both pygraphviz and pydot. It has both from_pydot and from_agraph methods. The swiss-army knife of python graph packages! I'm accepting this answer because somebody should point this out, and you did.